# Webpack 3.11 - ExtractTextPlugin - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type - Unexpected token

Tags: webpack, extracttextwebpackplugin

I like the error messages, they are very helpful (irony off)

[image]

**Error-Message:**

> webpack Hash: 9ff6bc2b8b3cb641bb93 Version: webpack 3.11.0 Time: 483ms
>           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
>       bundle.js    2.83 kB       0  [emitted]  main bundle.js.map    2.45 kB       0  [emitted]  main    index.html  188 bytes          [emitted]    [0] ./src/index.ts 320 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1
>   error]
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.ts Module parse failed: Unexpected token (50:44)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. |
>   setTimeout(() => { |     getComponent().then(component => { |
>   document.body.appendChild(component as HTMLDivElement); |
>   }).catch((e) => { |         console.log(e); Child html-webpack-plugin
>   for "index.html":
>        1 asset
>          [2](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/) (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
>          [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
>           + 2 hidden modules

**webpack.config.js, example code taken [from webpack.js.org v3.11](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/extract-text-webpack-plugin/)**

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// Create multiple instances
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-one.css');
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-two.css');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: extractLESS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ])
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractCSS,
    extractLESS
  ]
};
```

**Packages.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.2",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.5",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.102",
    "@types/webpack": "^3.8.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "less": "^3.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0"
  },
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [    
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "scripthost",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's failing on `index.ts`. Have you tried adding a rule for `ts-loader`? E.g., `{test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader'}`. More details on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader).

Comment: the `.ts` file is fine, it is something with the configuration... the error messages are misleading. It could also spit out "New York, the weather is shiny", this would be the equivalent of the above error message...

Answer (score 0):

**Works with Webpack v3.11**

I made some changes to the `webpack.config.js`, take a look below:

```
const {
    join
} = require('path')


const webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'stylesheets/[name]-two.css',
    disable: false,
    allChunks: true
});
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('stylesheets/[name]-one.css');

module.exports = {

    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    entry: join(__dirname, 'src/index'),

    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        extractLESS 
    ],

    devtool: "source-map",

    output: {
        path: join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.less']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractCSS.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader']
                })
            }, {
                test: /\.less$/i,
                use: extractLESS.extract(['css-loader', 'less-loader'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader']
            }             
        ],

    }
}
```

And in my index.ts file, I reference my less/css file(s):

**Index.ts**

```
   import "./css/style.css"
   import "./css/test.less"
```